# Random shutdown and reboots

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, shutdown

I have done the instructions below and when I get the random restarts the computer still restarts.

> "Open Windows Explorer (or just go to the desktop), right click on "Computer" and select "Properties". On the left, click "Advanced System Settings". (This will invoke a UAC dialog.) Find the Startup and Recovery section at the bottom of the window and click on "Settings". In the Startup and Recovery window, locate and uncheck the check box next to "Automatically Restart". Click "OK" until you're out of the window. No restart is needed."

Ran Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool

I have:

- replaced PSU Corsair CX600 watt,
- replaced CPU,
- ran Memtest86 several times on each of two sticks of RAM and together with no errors,
- ran Windows 10 Memory test with no errors.
- sent mobo to Gigabyte and it tests out good.
- ran Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool and CPU Passes test.
- checked temps all well below max on BIOS and SPECCY, and all fans running.

No error except event 41 kernel power task 63. I have completely reinstalled Windows 10 Pro at least twice. Still get random shut down and reboots. Machine can go for days without incident. Nothing in particular causes event. Can be simply staring at home screen and poof...random restart. Any pearls?

Comment: In the BIOS, look for a setting regarding how to handle power loss. Set this to "stay off" and see if it still reboots.

Comment: Already did this as well. Still restarts.